How do I prove this concisely with indicial notation?
I was doing problem 2.11 from the book Continuum Mechanics for Engineers (4th Ed.) and I just can't figure out how to solve this problem without filling out two whole whiteboards. I know there's got to be a concise way to do it, I just don't know how. Anybody care to help? The problem statement is as follows:

Use indicial notation to show that:
$ A_{mi}\varepsilon_{jkm} + A_{mj}\varepsilon_{kim} +
A_{mk}\varepsilon_{ijm} = A_{mm}\varepsilon_{ijk} $
Where $A$ is any tensor and $\varepsilon_{ijk}$ is the permutation symbol.


Let $T_{ijk}$ denote the sum on the LHS. I claim that it’s a completely anti symmetric rank-3 tensor. Indeed, we have
$$
T_{jki} = T_{ijk},\quad T_{jik} = -T_{ijk}.
$$
(Note that a cyclic permutation and a transposition generate all six permutations on three letters, so the above two relations imply the four other relations.) It follows that $T_{ijk} = T \epsilon_{ijk}$, where $T$ is a scalar. We can find it as follows:
$$
T= \frac16 T_{ijk} \varepsilon_{ijk} = \frac16 (A_{mi} \varepsilon_{mjk} \varepsilon_{ijk} + \cdots) = \frac16 (2 A_{mi} \delta_{mi} +\cdots) = A_{mm}.
$$

thx u! Really nice proof! I just have one question. Without the RHS being given, would it also be possible to deduce that the sum of terms on the LHS produces an anti-symmetric tensor? If so, how? I'd love to know.

@AndrewM. Even if you didn’t know the RHS, you can still see that the LHS is completely antisymmetric. That’s enough to deduce the RHS from LHS.

Ok, thx very much! I'll look more into that.

Ok maybe one last question though, sorry to keep bothering you. Yes, after looking at each one of LHS terms and writing them out explicitly it does become evident that each one produces an anti-symmetric tensor and thus, their sum, should yield an anti-symmetric tensor. However, without being given the RHS, how does it follow that "Tijk=Tϵijk, where T is a scalar". How would you know to make such a decomposition / factor out a constant term?

@AndrewM. You don’t have to write out all the components explicitly. First notice that $m$ is a repeated index on the LHS, whereas $i,j,k$ are free indices. Second, permuting the free indices gives us back the same sum up to a sign. There is a sign when the permutation of the free indices is odd. This is enough to conclude that the LHS is a completely anti symmetric tensor in the free indices.

ok thx, that is actually very helpful advice. However, how about figuring out that you can factor out a constant term from the RHS?
